# Page.isValid checks the whole page, not just the selected validation group

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have a few validators on my form, with 2 different `ValidationGroups`

before submitting the form, i only need to check for `ValidationGroup="main"` controls to be valid
i tried the following:

```
Page.Validate("main");
if (Page.IsValid) 
//do something
```

it kept returning `false` and i was going crazzzy.

after a check to see exactly which validator fails, it looks like it's chocking on a validator that is in a different `ValidationGroup`.

how can i make sure that it only validates "main" group?

this is my full submit code: (maybe i'm checking for failed validator wrong?) but either way i keep getting false for page.isvalid :(

```
Page.Validate("main");
            if ((Page.IsValid) && (user.userRole.Contains("9")))
                btnSubmit.Visible = true;
            else
            {
                foreach (BaseValidator valControl in Page.Validators)
                {
                    WebControl assControl = Page.FindControl(valControl.ControlToValidate) as WebControl;
                    if (valControl.IsValid)
                    {
                        //do something.

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //do something.
                        lblMessage.Text = valControl.ToString();
                    }

                } 
                btnSubmit.Visible = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwzxc386.aspx). It states that

> The Validate method validates the specified validation group. After
>   calling the Validate method on a validation group, the IsValid method
>   will return true only if both the specified validation group and the
>   validation group of the control that caused the page to be posted to
>   the server are valid.

Comment: i have this code in my page_load method. i'm not sure what "he control that caused the page to be posted to the server are valid." means :-/

Comment: @MadamZuZu which control raised the corresponding server side event? Also, if you are only concerned about certain validation group/controls, why you have validation on others?

Comment: the other validators are in a modal pop up panel. that are used when that pop up is triggered only...

Comment: @MadamZuZu Have you set ValidationGroup on the particular Submit button?

Comment: yes, but i want to check if the form is complete when it firsts loads, to eitehr how or hide a specific button (not one that causes validation)

Comment: You need to re-think about your problem! (sorry didn't understand what you mean in your last comment)